# how to get value for out parameter

Tags: c#

I know `TryParse` is not a member of `System.String` class, then how to get something similar like below for getting value in `out` parameter,

```
if (!string.TryParse(ConfigSettings.GetAppSetting("Test"), out var val))
        {
            val= "C:\\test";
        }
```

Below is possible,

```
if (!bool.TryParse(ConfigSettings.GetAppSetting("Test"), out var val))
        {
            val= 10;
        }
```

Just want to know for `string`, is this possible?

Comment: I don't follow what you're trying to do: do want want `val = ConfigSettings.GetAppSetting("Test")` unless if it's null or empty then default to c:\test ?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to achieve. Are you trying to *write* such a method, or do something else? Could you give a more complete example, and try to be clearer about which part you're stuck on?

Comment: You don't need to use TryParse for string because All dotnet types can be converted to string without any harm, not like string to int

Comment: Jon, just trying to know is this possible for string similar like double....question updated!

Comment: But bool.TryParse is easy to explain: try and convert a string into a boolean value. ConfigSettings.GetAppSettings presumably already returns a string, so I don't see what conversion is necessary. What is the logic you want your string.TryParse to do?

Comment: got it, now question is can I use out paremeter?

Comment: The `Out` parameters are to help in specific scenarios and not a compulsion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the variable can be scoped to condition, you can try this:

```
if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[valueKey] is string value)
{
    //...
}
else
{
    value = "C:\\test";
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No conversion is required while reading string values from `AppSettings`.

Below sample code is reading value for key "testKey" in `AppSettings`.

```
string testKeyValue = string.Empty;
if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[testKey] != null)
{
   testKeyValue = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[testKey];
}
```

Comment: understand that, but I need to create 1 variable, is this possible with `out` variable

Comment: In the answer, value is being set from appsetting key to variable name "testKeyValue ". What else do you want?